# Filter Requests based on Response Status Code Audit.Net

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, audit.net

I want to filter requests based on ResponseCode i.e requests with 500, 400, 401 etc response status codes should not be logged with Audit.Net.
I have used AuditMiddleware but it is not filtering 500, 400 and 401 requests responses.

Code:

```
 app.UseAuditMiddleware(_ => _
                .FilterByRequest(r => !r.Path.Value.EndsWith("favicon.ico") && r.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode==StatusCodes.Status200OK)
                .IncludeHeaders()
                .IncludeRequestBody()
                .IncludeResponseBody()
                .WithEventType("HTTP:{verb}:{url}"));
```

Then i called it in ConfigureApp method in StartUp.cs but it does not filter.

Answer (score 1):

The `FilterByRequest()` works as a pre-filter that is called *before* the action executes, so you won't have the response on the filter delegate.

The option to discard events based on the response is to do a post-filter via a [custom action](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions), for example on your startup:

```cs
using Audit.WebApi;

Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction(ActionType.OnEventSaving, scope =>
{
    var ev = scope.GetWebApiAuditAction();
    if (ev?.ResponseStatusCode == 500 || ev?.ResponseStatusCode == 400)
    {
        scope.Discard();
    }
});
```